# css code how to remove space between div class

Tags: html, css

my css is the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sign Up For Beta Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>

 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
}

p{margin-left:12px;}
.wrapper {
  margin:auto;
  height: 1500px;
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
   -webkit-flex: 3 1 60%;
           flex: 3 1 60%;
   -webkit-order: 2;
           order: 2;
}
#right {
  background: blue;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  height: 500px;
   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
}
#left {
  background: #333;
  position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
 margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  width: 67%;
  height: 500px;

   -webkit-flex: 1 6 20%;
           flex: 1 6 20%;
   -webkit-order: 3;
           order: 3;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #right, #left{display:block!important; width:100%;}

   .wrapper {
     display:block;
      width:80%
    -webkit-flex-flow: column;
            flex-direction: column;
   }

   #right, #left {
    /* Return them to document order */
    -webkit-order: 0;
            order: 0;
   }

  #right{
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
   }
}

</style>


  </head>


<body>

 <div class="wrapper">


<div id="left"><p>left section<p></div>
     <div id="right"><p>Right Section<p></div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

this code working well..What I need is that when I go to the mobile view I am getting space between two sides of the **"left section"** I want a small space when i go to the mobile view..
this is happening because I put **width:70%** in **wrapper class**...How to get little space between two sides of the **"left section div id**"..
[image]
I put the code into jsfiddle..here it is:

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/zt6gbs2z/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use media queries -

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 95%;
    }
}
```

This is the updated [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/zt6gbs2z/1/)
Resize the result screen